# Magento 1.x Get customer billing address

Tags: magento-1.9, php

Magento 1.x How to get a customer billing address in my custom module controller file?

Comment: What do you mean by custom file? Do you mean default billing address?

Comment: in my custom module controller file.

Comment: Yes I need customer Default billing address

Comment: On which page you want the default billing address of the customer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
$customerId = 2; // your customer ID
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId); // Load the customer with the help of customer model
$defaultBillingId  = $customer->getDefaultBilling(); // Return the default billing address ID

// Load the address by default billing Id will return the default billing address object
$defaultBillingAddress = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($defaultBillingId);
```

Comment: How to get customer id by default. If i give customer id by static also not working ., So can you please help me to solve it

Comment: Can you check the customer if he has default billing address or not?

Comment: Yes.. i checked.. customer having default billing address

Comment: Can you check what you are getting in this variable $defaultBillingId?

Comment: i checked in admin panel -> customer -> manage customers -> address-> default billing address is set

Comment: Ok. Can you check what you are getting in this variable $defaultBillingId?

Comment: Yes...  $defaultBillingId is 96

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95225/discussion-between-sukumar-gorai-and-lokesh-m).

Comment: Is it working correctly?